# Uploaded Images through PHP code not loading while directly uploading through C Panel are loading

Tags: javascript, php, html, cpanel, web-hosting

I have code for uploading images to my website. The images are uploading successfully both in localhost and remote host. But the problem is that when I am showing the images in a webpage they work fine in localhost and not working in remote host. When I try to access it through URL (visiting full path of the image) it works fine in localhost and showing 404 page not found error in remote host. The URL I am trying is correct also I looked the images in folders of my C panel they are uploading correctly. so what is the issue....?

When I upload some images manually in the same folder and then access these manually uploaded images they are working fine. but the images uploaded through php code are not loading...? Below is the complete code for uploading the images.

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit_images'])) {
    $name[1] = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
    $name[2] = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
    $name[3] = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
    $name[4] = $_FILES['image4']['name'];
    $name[5] = $_FILES['image5']['name'];
    $tmp_name[1] = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_name[2] = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_name[3] = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_name[4] = $_FILES['image4']['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_name[5] = $_FILES['image5']['tmp_name'];
    $success = 0;

    for ($c = 1; $c <= 5; $c++) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name[$c], "../assets/uploaded_images/" . $name[$c])) {
              $success++;
        }
    }
    $id++;
    echo "<script>alert('$success images Uploaded');</script>";
    if ($id <= 10) {
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php?id=$id','_self')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<h3 style='text-align:center;'>Thank You for Providing us the data.</h3>";
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: provide your php code for uploading images

Comment: <?php
include('connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit_images'])) {
    $name[1] = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
    $name[2] = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
    $name[3] = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
    $tmp_name[1] = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_name[2] = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_name[3] = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
    for ($c = 1; $c <= 3; $c++) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name[$c], "../assets/uploaded_images/" . $name[$c])) {            $success++;        }
    }
?>

Comment: Dr J Manish I am confused here because of the behavior that when I upload images manually in the same folder  they worked fine. and when they are uploaded through code they give the images uploaded successfully but not working...

Comment: are uploaded images via php exist in that folder ??

Comment: Yes they exist in that folder

Comment: secondly, what is code where you are showing images on webpage ?

Comment: _"The URL I am trying is correct"_ <- it really sounds like it isn't

Comment: Relative paths like `../assets/uploaded_images/` are usually the cause of such issues. Use a path relative to your current PHP script by using `__DIR__ . '/../assets/uploaded_images/...`

Comment: In the given pic the COIL.PNG is uploaded manually awhile the others are uploaded through code. the URL is http://paperjob.pk/datacollection/assets/uploaded_images/COIL.PNG

Comment: @phil I try __DIR__ . '/../assets/uploaded_images/ but again the same problem

Comment: check and  change the folder permission to `777` may be that solve the problem

Comment: @ Er. Amit Joshi folder already has 777 permission

Comment: what is the value showing for `__DIR__` variable or set it to ?

Comment: __DIR__ shows "/home/fuchwmtq/public_html/datacollection/images_collection" which is correct I think

Comment: secondly, what is code where you are showing images on webpage ?

Comment: Dr J Manish leave the code. the images should show by visiting it URL. You can see the above pic I have give. In the image I have uploaded "COIL.PNG" Manually it work fine by visiting "http://paperjob.pk/datacollection/assets/uploaded_images/COIL.PNG" while if you visit any other image show in the above picture they are present in the same directory but not working you can check it

Comment: E.g. http://paperjob.pk/datacollection/assets/uploaded_images/capital-region.jpg this is not working while the URL and Image name all things are correct.